# Set a column if another column is not empty

Tags: mysql, if-statement, set

I have a table where I want to switch a 1 to a 0 in one column, only if another column is not empty. I tried this, but I have a syntax error.

```
UPDATE table
SET column = 0 WHEN another_column is not null;
```

Comment: Try `WHERE` instead of `WHEN`

Comment: WHERE worked - solved!